# OpenVPN Setup - Service Won't Start

Tags: debian, vps, openvpn

I'm in the process of setting up OpenVPN on a VPS running Debian 6. I've walked step-by-step through [this guide](http://library.linode.com/networking/openvpn/debian-6-squeeze) twice now, and I can't get the service to start. When I start the service, the error reported in the log file is:

```
Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Inappropriate ioctl for device (errno=25)
```

I've searched the web a few times and I'm not finding anything helpful. I've tried:

- Changing file permissions: no change
- Deleting the file: get an error stating no file found (errno=2)
- Making a folder named "tun": get an error stating no file found (errno=2)

I've wiped my installation and completed the steps verbatim twice now. I get no errors along the way, just the error above within my log file. The contents of my server.conf file are listed below, minus all the comments for brevity. Can anyone help?

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert myserver.crt
key myserver.key
dh dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log         openvpn.log
verb 3
```

Comment: It's possible your VPS provider isn't running a kernel with the "tun" module.  Contact them to make sure about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of VPS do you have? You may need your provider to enable TUN/TAP devices on the host node.